# Transaction logging When rollback

Tags: spring, logging, spring-transactions

I have a requirement to log the transaction to Database irrespective of commit or rollback. Incase of Transaction rollback, while all the tables gets rolled back, I want to insert a record to Transaction log table. Please suggest the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

Spring generates traces for every rollback. Use an appender from your logging framework that inserts into your log table.